# HasOffer Pixel tracking

Tags: php, html

I am very beginner to use HasOffers.

I have created offer and Conversation tracking is: HTTP IFrame pixel.

I have get code for Iframe is following:

```
<iframe src="http://status.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=12" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
```

and i have put it in my code in `<body></body>` part and when I click on IFrame it store some value in my cookie in `enc_aff_session_895` and `ho_mob`.

how to know that user's detail after login in HasOffer?

and it is correct way ? it will work ?

I have followed 
https://help.tune.com/hasoffers/pixel-tracking/ for pixel tracking.

Comment: Read service docs and manuals?

Comment: i have follow  https://help.tune.com/hasoffers/pixel-tracking/ and i have use Iframe,but i am not getting that why conversion is not recorded , i have check conversion report but not find conversation

Comment: I have put ifame code after body tag to record conversation . but it not recorded conversation every time.

Answer (score 0):

The Iframe you mentioned is a Correct way, It should track conversions.

> how to know that user's detail after login in HasOffer?

You can find the user id from user manage page

> and it is correct way ? it will work ?

Yes it will work, Please test in Incognito window and disable any AdBlock plugin etc you are using.

I would like to recommend you another software where you can do easy test and have 24 hours Chat Call support. https://vnative.com/

Their Pixel Tracking https://vnative.com/adding-optional-parameters-postback-pixel-tracking-url/

Comment: I am new to hasOffer and want to pull offers from affiliates and should reflect in my hasofer network. I know 3 apis have to call, findAllOffer, tracking link api and then network api, where to do this? I am in the initial level, dont know what to do next, need to write a server side script or client side script? how to establish a connection with both server and hasOffer client? can you guys help me?

Comment: If you want to reduce your work, use any software which has already integration with Zapier or such to automate fetching of data and post data

Comment: I dont know anything about Zapier. Can you explain about this more?My doubt is 1. The scripts which we write dont need to deploy in a server right? 2. The scripts we write just have to run in the client side like automation.

Answer (score 0):

The enc_aff_session cookie will include the transaction_id, the transaction_id is the HasOffers term for the session identifier.
Once a conversion is tracked with that pixel (which looks correct by the way) you will see the event and transaction_id in the conversion report.

No need to use another platform if you already have a HasOffers account, HasOffers offers 24/7 support as well.